# How to use mocha unit test chokidar watch events

Tags: npm, events, mocha.js, watch, chokidar

I have the following pieces of nodejs code:

```js
    const watcher = chokidar.watch(path, {
          persistent: true
        });
    
        watcher
          .on('add', path=> {
            // func1();
          })
          .on('change', path=> {
            // func2();
          })
          .on('unlink', path=> {
            // func3();
          });
```

I need to use mocha to write some unit test cases to test the above code, but I'm not familiar with mocha and not sure how to trigger these add/change/unlink events. I've tried to use mock-fs, but it seems like it can only simulate the 'add' event. Can somebody help me if you have any idea?

```js
    it('should read file when file is added or changed, log error when file is removed', function () {
       // on 'add' event
       chai.assert.isTrue(func1.isCalled);
       // on 'change event
       chai.assert.isTrue(func2.isCalled);
       // on 'unlink'
       chai.assert.isTrue(func3.isCalled);    
    });
```